# Why are different methods used for passing data to a server via jquery ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I was given an old project to update. I noticed that form or other data sent to the server via jQuery's ajax method passed the data like so:

data: '{ name1 : "value1", name2 : "value2" }'

In new projects, though, I've passed the data formatted as a querystring, like so:

data: 'name1=value1&name2=value2'

The old project won't accept the querystring style of data. I've read that you can create a model and then submit the data as a JSON object based on that model. Sounds great, but the Asp.net procedure called by ajax won't accept the data, even though it has a parameter of that model type.

Appreciate your insights...

EDIT: Here is code from old (Asp.Net Webforms) and new (Asp.Net MVC) projects.
OLD:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '<%=Microsoft.AspNet.FriendlyUrls.FriendlyUrl.Resolve("MyPage.aspx/MyAction")%>',
    data: "{MyParam : '" + MyVar + "' }",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    error: function (xhr, textStatus, errMsg) {
        console.log(xhr.responseText);
    },
    success: function (data) {
    // ... things to do.
    }
});
```

NEW:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/MyController/MyAction',
    cache: false,
    data: 'MyName1=' + MyValue1
        + '&MyName2=' + encodeURIComponent(MyValue2)
        + '&MyName3=' + encodeURIComponent($('#MySpan3').html())
        + '&MyName4=' + MyValue4,
    datatype: 'json',
    error: function (xhr, textStatus, errMsg) {
        console.log(xhr.responseText);
    },
    success: function (data) {
    // ... things to do.
    }
});
```

Comment: Why should they work in the same way? `'{ name1 : "value1", name2 : "value2" }' !== 'name1=value1&name2=value2'`

Comment: We'd need to see your ajax POST *and* asp.net action parameters to determine why it's not recognising your data.  Try it with separate parameters rather than a "model" first.

Comment: Maybe your action has [`[FromBody]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.frombodyattribute?view=aspnetcore-5.0) attribute?  So it must be in the POST *body* to be recognised and not on the query string.

Comment: As to *why* - depends on the server/service.  Some require in the query string, some require in the POST body, some require json encoded, some require `application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8` etc

Comment: The first method should not have quotes around `{...}`

Comment: Because the old project was written poorly, unless you misrepresented it in your question (nothing should be accepting invalid json)

Comment: Did you try sending JSON, like `data: JSON.stringify({ name1 : "value1", name2 : "value2" })`

Comment: @Musa, yes I did try JSON.stringify.

Answer (score -1):

The best way is to pass an object rather than a string.

```
data: { name1 : "value1", name2 : "value2" }
```

jQuery will convert that to the equivalent `name1=value1&name2=value2` format. But it will also ensure that the names and value are properly URL-encoded. If you construct the string yourself, you need to call `encodeURIComponent()` for any dynamic values that might contain special characters.